# É possível criar o método main numa classe abstrata?

Tags: java

Posso utilizar o método `main` numa classe abstrata?

Uma classe abstrata não pode ser instanciada, isso eu sei. Pode ser referenciada, sim.

Mas eu posso utilizar o método `main` nela?

Não estou falando de "compila ou não compila" estou falando de uma boa prática de programação.

Posso ou não?

Exemplo:

```
public abstract class funcionario{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Funcionario f1 = new Diretor();
    }
}
```

Comment: Defina "boa prática de programação" e nós podemos começar a conversar sobre isso.

Comment: A questão aqui é: por que alguém faria isso? Qual o objetivo de se colocar o ponto de entrada de uma aplicação numa classe abstrata? Mais do que isso: qual o sentido de colocar numa classe que parece (pelo nome) ter sido criada para interagir com os dados da aplicação?

Comment: A pergunta principal aqui é:  pra que você quer por main numa classe abstrata? Não consigo imaginar nenhum situaçao pra isso.

Comment: @Articuno LOL Parece que a gente combinou

Comment: Embora de certo não seja a melhor pergunta do site, considero uma pergunta clara (e portanto discordo do voto de fechamento) e também considero uma pergunta legítima (e portanto discordo dos votos negativos).

Answer (score 6):

Você pode fazer isso, mas não costuma fazer muito sentido na prática.

Um método, mesmo que seja o `main`, idealmente tem uma ligação com a classe onde ele está. Isso tem relação direta com o [princípio da responsabilidade única](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle), com o [princípio da alta coesão](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cohesion_(computer_science)) e com o [princípio do baixo acoplamento](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupling_(computer_programming)).

Assim sendo, o local ideal para colocar-se o `main` depende bastante da arquitetura e estrutura do seu programa. Se houver uma classe que naturalmente já representa o seu programa inteiro sendo executado, faz sentido que o `main` fique lá para manter a alta coesão e o baixo acoplamento, **mesmo se essa classe for abstrata**. Entretanto, dificilmente faria sentido uma classe abstrata representar o seu programa como um todo, e portanto **dificilmente isso faria sentido**. Além disso, se a classe que representa o seu programa como um todo for uma classe abstrata, ela provavelmente estaria fazendo coisas demais, violando o princípio da responsabilidade única.

Nos casos onde não há uma classe que representa o programa como um todo, você colocaria o método `main` em uma classe apenas para ele. A responsabilidade única dessa classe seria a de ser o ponto de entrada do programa. Naturalmente, não faria sentido algum essa classe ser abstrata.

Aliás, na prática o próprio conceito de classe abstrata é uma coisa que vem sendo bastante questionada como resultado do conceito de herança de implementação estar sendo questionado. A herança introduz um forte acoplamento da subclasse para a superclasse e é uma coisa que quase sempre pode ser eliminada com refatorações e ser substituída por composição. A herança de tipo é trabalhada com interfaces. A partir do Java 8, você pode ter implementações `default` e estática em interfaces, o que reduz ainda mais a necessidade de utilizar herança e com isso a necessidade de utilizar-se classes abstratas ao prover herança de implementação também por meio de interfaces.

Em resumo, se você está preocupado com boas práticas de programação, possivelmente você acabará com um projeto onde não haverá nenhuma classe abstrata (ou restarão pouquíssimas), e portanto não haveria nenhuma delas onde você colocaria o `main`.

No seu caso específico, parece que você tem `Diretor extends funcionario`. Ocorre que seria melhor que `Funcionario` tivesse um método `public Cargo getCargo()` e então você teria `public class Diretor implements Cargo`. Isso deixaria a estrutura do seu projeto mais organizada e eliminaria a herança e com ela a necessidade de ter-se classes abstratas.

Além disso, o fato do `main` estar na classe `funcionario` demonstra que ocorreu uma violação do princípio da responsabilidade única nessa classe. O fato do `main` provavelmente utilizar muitas outras coisas além de funcionário (em especial ao acoplar a superclasse na subclasse em vez do contrário) também demonstra que o acoplamento é alto ao invés de baixo e a coesão é baixa ao invés de alta.

Assim sendo, sua pergunta é um pouco um [problema XY](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/499/132). O método `main` estar em uma classe abstrata é um *bad smell*, mas na verdade "o buraco está mais em baixo".

Comment: Acho que o problema nem é usar uma classe abstrata para o método `main`, e sim definir uma classe que representa um `Funcionario` como abstrata. Não haveria problema algum ter uma classe `Main` abstrata com um método estático `main`, já que um método estático não precisa de uma instância para ser executado, e deixar a classe `Main` como abstrata só impediria ela de ser instanciada em outro lugar.

Comment: @gato Sim, o problema é `funcionario` ser abstrata. Quanto a haver uma classe `Main` abstrata, o melhor seria usar o padrão recomendado para classes que não possam ser instanciadas: colocar o modificador `final` na classe e declarar nela um único construtor sem parâmetros, privado e que lança uma `UnsupportedOperationException`.